# Rendered Video Causing Artifacts In Adobe Media Encoder

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, video

So, I've rendered this video (took about 25hrs(Mac book Pro 2015)), and now when I put try to encode it to .mxf it has lots of artifacts. I'll provide links and Blender file Below.

Here is a picture from Premiere Pro's timeline: [image]

Here is the original video clip: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F6AnVLV3z39P1WCsYUh8OVgpwxwUH4Qo/view?usp=sharing

Here is the .mxf file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YfI_ytThNXYAT-dZi5yT7TRH5-2qIjGC/view?usp=sharing

And the blender file (for the settings): [image]

Comment: Why are you encoding twice? Don't render as video, render once as an image sequence (preferably as OpenEXR or 16 bit Tiff or PNG) and encode later, so that you can try different settings until you find one that works.This looks like an issue with the encoder (probably the bitrate is set too low or something like that). Not an issue in blender any way.

Comment: Well, I encoded it, but Davinci Resolve couldn't read it, so I encoded it in AME. But even in Premiere Pro it's really artifacted. How do you take the Image sequence of TIFF and make it a video easily? I'm not setting 720 images to 1 frame.